# How to declare (and pass) Julia function parameters when the parameter could be one of two types

Tags: function, parameters, julia

My goal is to pass an `IOStream` variable to a Julia function (if I want to write to an open file), or `nothing` (or possibly something else that would be considered an empty or null value). The reason is that I might call this function numerous times and would like to keep the file handle open regardless of how many times I enter the function. If the intent is not to write to the file, I would simply pass `nothing`  indicating to the function not to attempt writing to a file.

I have tried declaring as:

```
function f(x, y, f)
```

and as:

```
function f(x, y, f::IOStream)
```

and as:

```
function f(x, y, f::Any)
```

while passing in a variable set to either `nothing` or an `IOStream` resulting from a

```
open("filename.txt", "a")
```

statement. In all cases, I get an error of some sort. Is there some other way to achieve my goal, or should I be using a different type of function declaration/call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not have the same name for function and parameter. Anyway there are two approaches - either you use type `Union` or multiple dispatch.

Hence your code can be either:

```
function f(x, y, fs::Union{IOStream,Nothing}=nothing)
    #code goes here
end
```

or you can do:

```
function f(x, y, fs::IOStream)
    #code goes here
end
function f(x, y, fs::Nothing)
    #code goes here
end
```

Instead of the second function you could as well just do:

```
function f(x, y)
    #code goes here
end
```

Comment: Thank you Przemyslaw - I did not know about Union - very helpful.